# Expanding Pandas Dataframe for New Variable Set

Tags: pandas

I need to expand a Dataframe for a superset of variables, where missing columns and rows corresponding to the missing variables will get zero values. For example,

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','c'],['b','d']],columns = ['u1','u3'])
print (df)
```

```
  u1 u3
0  a  c
1  b  d
```

When I have a new column list `['u1','u2','u3']` this Dataframe should become

```
  u1  u2 u3
0  a   0  c
1  0   0  0
2  b   0  d
```

where a new zero column *and* row is added at the second position, resulting the new zero values seen above. What would be the proper / fast way of doing this in Pandas? I know about `pad`, `concat`, many other calls in Pandas, but got nothing for this one.

Note: I needed this feature for an engineering application where a global "stiffness" matrix is created piece by piece, for different parts of a structure with seperate matrices. The global variable list is a superset of the individual parts, and for a proper "superposition" the variable list of the pieces need to match, hence the need for an expanded set.

Comment: how would this generalize? do you always have 2x2 becoming 3x3?

Comment: no actually, 4 x 4 can become 5 x 5, i need this for any N x N

Comment: Then please give other examples for clarity. Also please explain if the column names in the final DataFrame are lexicographically ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dataframe is always square, you can use:

```
V = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3']

df1 = (df.set_axis(df.columns)
         .reindex(V, axis=0, fill_value=0)
         .reindex(V, axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  u1  u2 u3
0  a   0  c
1  0   0  0
2  b   0  d
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

Your index looks like a RangeIndex, and since u2 is the new second column, it looks like you want to create the second row with 0s. Try the following code:

```
new_cols = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3']
out = df.set_axis(df.columns)\
        .reindex(index=new_cols, columns=new_cols, fill_value=0)\
        .reset_index(drop=True)
```

out

```
  u1 u2 u3
0  a  0  c
1  0  0  0
2  b  0  d
```

Answer (score 1):

After I asked I thought up an approach myself, basically using the column names also in the index, so I would be inserting a new `u2` column and `u2` row,

```py
new_cols = ['u1','u2','u3']
df2 = df.copy()
df2['u2'] = np.nan
df2.loc['u2'] = pd.Series(df2.columns)
df2 = df2[new_cols]
df2.reindex(new_cols).fillna(0)
```

```
   u1   u2 u3
u1  a  0.0  c
u2  0  0.0  0
u3  b  0.0  d
```

However the previous answers are more slick. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what our answers (@PandaKim and I) do: `.set_axis(new_cols)` except you don't see it because we reset the index.